# SSL certificate from GoDaddy on NodeJS and express not working

Tags: node.js, ssl

I have a NodeJs Application running with express. I have been trying to integrate an SSL certificate but I keep having the same `error: Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line.`

I have tried some solutions I found on stackOverflow like

```
if (process.env.SSL_PRIVATE_KEY  && process.env.SSL_CERTIFICATE) {
      server = require('https');
      server.createServer({
        key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('ssl/key.pem'), 'utf8'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('ssl/server.crt'), 'utf8'),
        ca: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('ssl/bundle.crt'), 'utf8'),
        requestCert: false,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    
      }, app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
        console.log('Express server listening on https://localhost:' + app.get('port'));
      });
    } else {
      server = require('http');
      server.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
        console.log('Express server listening on http://localhost:' + app.get('port'));
      });
```

But none seem to work. My main problem is that I donwloaded my certificate file from GoDaddy but I only get two .cert files. I have read in some websites how to obtain the .pem files but I keep getting the same error.

As you can see I am new at using https protocol in NodeJs.

Could you help me solve this problem?

Best regards

Comment: Are the certificates in binary form (DER) or base64 (PEM) form? Open the files in a text editor and you will see if it is binary (DER) or text (PEM). Most Linux/Unity programs expect certificate s and keys in PEM format.

Comment: When I downloaded the file it came in .PEM format. I will show you the following content:

 `----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE -----`
`{{content}}`
`----- END CERTIFICATE -----`

But it still doesn't work for me, what could it be?

@Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already solved. Actually the files that GoDaddy gave me was in the wrong format, therefore I called support, they did not know how to solve it and I had to refund the money, therefore, add the HTTPS protocol with Let's Encrypt.

Answer (score 0):

From godaddy, you will have 5 file:
1- Key which is in Text Format
2- CSR Text format
3- pem file
4- crt file
5- bundle crt file

What you have to do is rename the key to a .pem file then open then change the format to utf8. On Mac

- Open TextEditor
- Select open file but before opening file click on options on the bottom left
- Select UTF8 encoding
- Select the Key.pem file
- Once it opens, save it

The code with fs.ReadfileSync will work one: First is the Key file, second is the PEM file downloaded, and third is the bundle